How to see number of storage volumes on AWS RDS MySQL?
According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html, for "400–65,536 GiB" storage MySQL RDS will use "Number of volumes provisioned = 4".
I have an instance with 2TB gp3 storage and, according to Cloudwatch IOPS and LVM_IOPS metrics, instance has one storage volume - i.e. I see the same  numbers for LVMWriteIOPS and WriteIOPS.
Is there a way to see how many storage volume my RDS instance has?
